# Macro for typesetting acronyms

Tags: macros, typography, acronyms, capitalization

All-caps acronyms and brand names like IBM look better when typeset a little smaller than usual. My simple solution is the following macro:

```
\def\<#1>{{\small #1}}
```

It's used like here `\<IBM>` and `\<CACM>`. However, it does not work well in section titles and the like. One could use small caps instead but I find those likewise standing out too much. Any better ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? How would you handle this: The U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual? If the "U.S" is set at a smaller size it will look odd. One idea is to use a `tt` font. Sometimes, I use it for Company names and it blends well.

Comment: @Yiannis Your point is valid as there is no universal solution when acronyms are mixed with other words. One could use `\textsc{U.S. Government Printing Office Style Manual}` but would have to use this consistently. The Economist, for example, is using small caps for acronyms. I was looking for a solution when acronyms are written without periods, like in ISO or NAFTA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `\textsmaller{#1}` of the [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because your font does not support bold small caps? See this post:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699371/latex-small-caps-and-bold-face