# Mixing uppercase, lowercase, and small caps?

Tags: xetex, acronyms, small-caps

**The problem**

I want to follow [The Economist's example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9539/9092) for annoyingly mixed-case words: letterspace them, capitalize the first letter according to normal rules, and set all other capitals as small capitals. And I'd like it to be as transparent as possible – one command, `\ac`, in the normal case and another, `\Ac`, when capitalized.

**My attempt**

In XeLaTeX, `\ac` can be implemented with a simple font change. But `\Ac` needs to apply that font change to all but the first letter. I found something similar (the `\Upeach` command) in [a 2007 TUGboat article by Peter Wilson](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88glister.pdf) and modified it a little.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Define \ac
\newfontface\acface[Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps,LetterSpace=6]{Minion Pro}
\newcommand{\ac}[1]{{\acface #1}}

% Define \Ac
%%% Non-working code removed; see the TUGboat article for the original
%%% Or egreg's answer for a much better solution
```

**The actual questions**

1. Is there a simpler way to do this than butchering `\Upeach`?
2. Can the butchered `\Upeach` be modified to stop it from eating spaces?

Comment: What about using the `glossaries` package with the `smallcaps` option?  It provides `\gls` which does what your `\ac` does (with the added bonus of providing the definition upon first use) and `\Gls` which does what your `\Ac` does (also provides `\glspl` for plurals etc.).  I assume this is too translucent for you, but just wanted to mention it if you have not considered it.

Comment: @mforbes With the `smallcaps` option, `\gls` makes lowercase small caps. If I `\let\acronymfont\ac` then `\gls` makes uppercase small caps. But then `\Gls` just sets the entire acronym as small caps (i.e., no lowercase or uppercase), which is emphatically *not* what I want.

Comment: I was suggesting the other way round: Set the main font `\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=6}]{Minion Pro}`, then use the `glossaries` commands `\let\ac\gls`, and `\let\Ac\Gls`.  I see that it is somewhat difficult to redefine `\acronymfont` to select a specific font and to get the capitalization working because of the grouping required to contain the font selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with

```
\makeatletter
\def\Ac#1{\@Ac#1\@Ac}
\def\@Ac#1#2\@Ac{#1\kern.05em{\acface#2}}
\makeatother
```

Adjust the `\kern` to match the letterspacing in the second part.

The first letter is typeset "as is", while the rest is subject to `\acface`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be a simpler way. If it's not too much trouble, do you know of any good, basic resources on doing these sorts of manipulations? Right now I'm pretty much hopelessly lost once I see `\makeatletter`.

Comment: @rdhs This doesn't work correctly if called as `\Ac{P}`, but it shouldn't be a problem. I'm afraid that one has to read the TeXbook or TeX by Topic to master this kind of things.