# Uppercase Smallcaps with LaTeX (not XeLaTeX)?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, small-caps

In `XeLaTeX` there is an `UppercaseSmallCaps` font option (as mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36503/mixing-uppercase-lowercase-and-small-caps) for example) that will cause upper-case letters to be rendered in small-caps and lower-case letters to remain.

**Question:** How can `UppercaseSmallCaps` be implemented in plain `LaTeX` (or `pdfLaTeX`) so that text like `\upsc{ABCdef}` will be rendered as `\textsc{abc}def`?

Comment: Hmmm.  Having a really hard time deciding between egreg and Joseph Wright's solutions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[convert,border=1]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifsc@active
\newif\ifnf@active
\def\upsc#1{{\sc@activefalse\nf@activetrue\@upsc#1\@nil}}
\def\@upsc#1{\ifx#1\@nil\else\@@upsc{#1}\expandafter\@upsc\fi}
\def\@@upsc#1{%
  \ifnum\uccode`#1=`#1\relax
     \ifsc@active\else\sc@activetrue\nf@activefalse\scshape\fi
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
     \ifsc@active\sc@activefalse\fi
     \ifnf@active\else\nf@activetrue\normalfont\fi
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
     {\lowercase{#1}}%
     {#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\upsc{xABCdovff}
\end{document}
```

Doesn't work with accented letters, of course.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the point of the question that we're _not_ allowed to use XeTeX?

Comment: @JosephWright Now it works with pdflatex (and does ligatures and kerning when possible).

Comment: Nice fast solution!  Better than Joseph's solution in that it is an order of magnitude faster and does ligatures and kerning, but it does not allow for spaces, paragraphs etc.

Comment: @mforbes No, of course. But I believed it was for acronyms or abbreviations.

Comment: `\def\upsc#1{{...}}` should have an enclosing group so that the smallcaps do not leak.  Will fix later when I test more thoroughly.

Comment: @mforbes Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe a bit over the top, but you could use [`l3regex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/l3experimental) to achieve this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3regex,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_rescan:nn { nV } 
\NewDocumentCommand \upsc { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([A-Z]+) }
      { \c{textsc} \cB\{ \c{lowercase} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} \cE\} } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\upsc{ABCabcDEF}
\end{document}
```

This uses the latest experimental version of `l3regex`, which is on CTAN and which has an 'extended regex' system to allow the inclusion of category-code information in the search and replace text.

You could set up a search for upper-case letters in the same way using alternative methods (such as [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xtring)).

---

**Explanation of the code**

The basic idea here is to store the text, do a replacement then print it again. I've chosen to replace each upper case <Letter> by

```
\textsc{\lowercase{<Letter>}}
```

The search part is a simple regex `([A-Z]+)`, which will capture the letter as `\1` (in the replace part). There, `\c{textsc}` will create the control sequence `\textsc` in the updated text and `\c{lowercase}` creates `\lowercase`. `\1` is the captured letter from the search part, while `\cB\{` and `\cE\}` possibly need a bit of explanation. In the replacement text, `\cB\{` creates the character `{` (which needs to be escaped) with category code 'Begin group'. Similarly, `\cE\}` creates the character `}` with category code 'End group'.

The final stage is to insert the result into the input stream. If you want to see what is happening, try adding `\tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl` after the `\tl_use:N` line.

Comment: You can't use `fontspec` with pdfTeX, so `UppercaseSmallCaps` is not directly relevant.

Comment: Support for accents would be more challenging (they'll work in the lower case part but not the upper case part).

Comment: Nice demonstration of LaTeX3!  Better than egreg's in that it works with spaces and paragraphs (with a small modification), but an order of magnitude slower, and disables kerning...

Comment: One comment: if you want this to work with macros, then you should replace `\tl_set:Nn` with `\tl_set:Nx` so that those macros get expanded.  This is needed, for example, if trying to use this with the `glossaries` package: `\renewcommand*{\acronymfont}[1]{\upsc{#1}}`.

Comment: @mforbes You'd want `\protected@edef` with any user input: not all LaTeX2e commands will be happy inside a raw `x`-type expansion

Comment: So I would `\protected@edef\tmp{#1}` then `\tl_set:No \l_tmpa_tl \tmp` to be safe?

Comment: @mforbes No, I just meant `\protected@edef \l_tmpa_tl {#1}`: there are some 2e concepts that really can't be avoided.