# Abbreviations in mixed cases in small caps

Tags: fonts, typography, acronyms, small-caps

Some guidelines suggest the use of use small caps for abbreviations. I have an issue with the following one: iTRAQ. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9534/using-small-caps-for-abbreviations)
 are some guidelines on mixed small-upper case abbreviations. I do want to keep the small-caps version visually as close as possible to the standard one.

`iTRAQ`, `i\textsc{traq}`, and `i\kern.07em\textsc{traq}` look like this with the font charter:

[image]

The *i* in the two capitalized versions is larger than the small-caps afterwards and also *TRAQ* is lighter than the other text. Is there a good general solution for mixed-case abbreviations?

---

**Update 1**. Charter does not use real small caps, but scales the font, that's why *TRAQ* is so light. With `kpfonts`, which has true small caps, it looks slightly better, but still strange as the `i` is larger than the caps:

[image]

---

**Update 2**. Using Barbara Beeton's/tugboat's solution, I am happy with the result (second variant in the image):

[image]

Using `small` in `normalsize` environment, etc., to have fake (or true?) small-caps produces an results which is, for my eyes, visually appealing. The abbreviations are slightly lighter than true small-caps, but I can life with that for the benefit of having an universal solution.

Comment: Small caps is only a suggestion, and ought to be ignored when not appropriate, as I think is the case here. To be perfectly honest, I think the lowercase `i` is an affectation, unless this is a trademark.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a [trademark][http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRAQ], and people would recognize it in that writing style with lower-case i. The text in which I use this abbreviation is long and contains many more abbreviations - I guess I use small caps either for all or none?

Comment: because all caps is too overwhelming, and ordinary small caps are felt to be too small, tugboat uses a command called `\SMC` (accessed by a derivative command `\acro`) to set caps one size smaller (but still using caps).  the code is fairly involved, but we like the results.  see the file `ltugboat.cls`; it is included in a full tex live installation, or can be found on ctan.

Comment: That indeed is a nice solution, @barbarabeeton! I have the same feeling regarding the sizes, small-caps do stand in many fonts as very small. Furthermore, as there is no big difference between normal-small, etc., the small-caps are also not too light when using your approach (in contrast with sc carter, for example). Could add an answer which I'd be glad to accept?

Answer (score 3):

CW from the comments: The TUGboat solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter % code from ltugboat.cls:1477-1494
\DeclareRobustCommand{\SMC}{%
  \ifx\@currsize\normalsize\small\else
   \ifx\@currsize\small\footnotesize\else
    \ifx\@currsize\footnotesize\scriptsize\else
     \ifx\@currsize\large\normalsize\else
      \ifx\@currsize\Large\large\else
       \ifx\@currsize\LARGE\Large\else
        \ifx\@currsize\scriptsize\tiny\else
         \ifx\@currsize\tiny\tiny\else
          \ifx\@currsize\huge\LARGE\else
           \ifx\@currsize\Huge\huge\else
            \small\SMC@unknown@warning
 \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\SMC@unknown@warning}{\TBWarning{\string\SMC: nonstandard
    text font size command -- using \string\small}}
\newcommand{\textSMC}[1]{{\SMC #1}}
\newcommand{\acro}[1]{\textSMC{#1}\@}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\iTRAQ}{i\acro{TRAQ}}

\begin{document}
This is an example of using \iTRAQ\ in running text.
\end{document}
```

[image]