# Make small caps copyable as capital letters in PDF

Tags: pdftex, pdf, viewers, small-caps

I'm using `pdflatex` to typeset a document where the style guide mandates that acronyms be written in small caps.  So for example, I might write,

```
Hearing aids do not cure \textsc{aids}.
```

to produce the text "Hearing aids do not cure AIDS."

The problem is that when I select and copy this text from the PDF, it gets rendered in the clipboard as "Hearing aids do not cure aids.", thus obscuring a crucial distinction in meaning.

I can reproduce this behaviour with several different PDF viewers, including Okular, Evince, and Adobe Reader.

How can I ensure that acronyms are visually rendered with small caps in the PDF, but rendered with actual capital letters when text is copied and pasted from the PDF?  (Note that I also use small caps in my document headers, so I don't want to change the behaviour of `\textsc` generally.)

Comment: You could think about using the TUGboat solution: [Abbreviations in mixed cases in small caps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148925/35864), or [Macro for typesetting acronyms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9487/35864), where you circumvent the problem by using CAPS, but scaling them down a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I came up with after noticing a related question, [Making equations copyable in pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf).  I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing things, but it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand*{\copyablesc}[1]{%
  \BeginAccSupp{%
    ActualText=\detokenize{#1},%
    method=escape,
  }%
  \textsc{\lowercase{#1}}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}
Hearing aids do not cause \copyablesc{AIDS}.
\end{document}
```