# Small caps that are actually uppercase in the output PDF

Tags: pdf, small-caps

In my document, I've typeset abbreviations in small caps so that they don't stand out from the surrounding text.

Here is a small example:

```latex
JavaScript and \textsc{html}
```

Using `tectonic`, this produces:

[image: example of small caps]

I'm satisfied with how this looks, but when I select and copy the "HTML" in the PDF output, it's "html", lowercase. Is there any way to make it uppercase? Or, perhaps, is this a cursed thing to do?

---

Edit: I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269765/make-small-caps-copyable-as-capital-letters-in-pdf), which seems to be what I'm looking for. However, the accepted solution (using accsupp) didn't work when I tried it; the text was still lowercase.

Comment: Welcome to text.se.

Comment: Can your provide a small compileable code example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: I think `accsupp` is the only viable solution (but might be mistaken, at least it's what I'd have suggested). Note that not every PDF viewer seems to listen to it, so it might actually work, but just not with your viewer.

Comment: the alternative would be to use `{\small HTML}` (or some other fitting font size).

Comment: Another semi-viable solution might be to modify the small caps font such that upper case letters are actually rendered in (real) small caps and then use `\textsc{HTML}`.