# Type setting the name of algebraic software

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I need to refer to the algebra systems MAGMA and GAP throughout my work. I have often seen people write the names so they are capitalised in a pretty way. How do they do this?

Answer (score 3):

For example using small caps, with `xspace` in addition:

```
\newcommand*{\MAGMA}{\textsc{magma}\xspace}
```

Comment: Just for reference: [Drawbacks of xspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/4918)

Comment: Here is another solution that does not use `\xspace`: [Macro for typesetting acronyms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9487/3083).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `glossaries` approach (which might come into real usefullness if there are more than just GAP and MAGMA)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{gap}{GAP}{Groups, Algorithms and Programming}
\newacronym{magma}{MAGMA}{Acronym still to be defined}

\makeglossaries

\glsunsetall
\begin{document}
\gls{magma} and \gls{gap} are useful computer algebra software systems. 

%\printacronyms
\end{document}
```